# Publish json string message to RabbitMq exchange using masstransit

Tags: json, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

Recently we implemented event/queue support to our apps using MassTransit, before this we used a custom implementation of RabbitMQ. In that implementation we had a scheduling mechanism similar to MassTransit but we were using a standalone Hangfire instance, and this was implemented in a way that a json string was given to Hangfire so it would publish the string to specified queue on schedules. Now we need same functionality with MassTransit but wondering how could it be done?

I already tried many solutions including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69555944/1818708) & [video](https://youtu.be/xOxSLNeN5CU) of Chris Patterson and no success. My actual problem is on serialization & routing side, I need to call `Publish` method passing a string which is a json representation of a dotnet record & not facing with the system types can't be used and finally the message delivered to my desired exchange.

Comment: MassTransit has it's own [Hangfire](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/scheduling#hangfire) integration for scheduling messages.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thanks, I've seen that already but I don't want my every project (or microservices) have their own hangfire instance. Is there a way to integrate it with the standalone one?

Comment: You would only have one Hangfire instance per message broker, it would be shared by all services using that broker.

Comment: Can please explain it more, how it could be possible? and as we have one already, can it be used also?